# Cannot open a webservice that i published into IIS7 installed on my windows 7 frpm a different computer on different netwrok

Tags: website, visual-studio

I have published my website into inetpub in windows 7. I can open the website on my computer using my IP adress and also i can open it on a different home computer. But, when i give the URL to my friends on a different network, they cannot open it. It says connection timed out.
I have used Visual studio to build my web service.

Plase help

Answer (score 1):

Chances are your IP address is non routable  (provide the first 2 octets of the IP, so we can tell).

Another possibility is that a gateway/firewall somewhere on the way between your friend's client and the server prevents the connection.

Answer (score 1):

My initial test would be to make sure your friend is able to talk to your computer. Try to execute the PING or TRACERT command from your friends computer to your computer.

If that command is successful then the error may be something else.

Execute following MS DOS COMMAND from your friends computer

**TRACERT xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx  (IP Address of your computer)**

OR

**PING xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx**